# Echo target description in Ant

Tags: java, ant

```
<target name="compile" description="Compile the File">
        <echo>Compile the File </echo>
        <mkdir dir="${compilation-dir}" />
        <javac srcdir="." classpath="another2" destdir="${compilation-dir}" />
    </target>
```

I want to echo the description of the target. Is there a better way of doing this other than duplicating it?

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is not a perfect solution, but at least you avoid duplicate descriptions.

```
<property name="testing.desc" value="this is the desc" />

<target name="testing" description="${testing.desc}">
    <echo message="${testing.desc}" />
</target>
```

Comment: if i do this the property does not expand with -projecthelp .. (ant 1.8.2)