# Is there a way to expand an ant property inside a target description?

Tags: ant

Is it possible to have ant help use values of properties inside a target description? Just using the ${} notation doesn't seem to work

build file:

```
<property name="test.report.dir"           value="report"/>
...
<target name="test" depends="compile.main, compile.test" description="Runs unit tests. Reports are saved in ${test.report.dir}/">
...
```

terminal:

```
ant -p

Buildfile: /home/aaron/Projects/DataStore/build.xml

Main targets:
...
 test                   Runs unit tests. Reports are saved in ${test.report.dir}/
...
```

This was suggested as a solution in [Echo target description in Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754631/echo-target-description-in-ant), but as a commenter noted, it doesn't expand the property.

I'm using ant 1.9.3 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. A target description is read as it is: no property evaluation is done. It makes sense because:

- A target description is expected to provided a general information about the behavior of the target, which is irrelevant to the value of a certain property.
- The project help `-p` option does not execute the Ant tasks contained in a buildfile, so it cannot evaluate properties defined using the `property` task.